# How can you specify a different matrix permutation for each element in a batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a constant symmetric matrix `A` with shape `(50,50)` and inputs `x` with shape `(batch_size, 50)` where each entry is an integer in `[0,49]` - these correspond to indexes in `A`.

I wish to create a new tensor with shape `(batch_size, 50, 50)` where each element in the batch is the matrix `A` permuted according to the ordering given in the input `x`. Each input has a different ordering of the integers from 0 to 49. Then, this

The only way I've thought to do this does not work, and I fear it would be inefficient even if it didn't give an error:

```
#Given x and A
x = np.zeros((b, 50))
for i in range(b):
  x[b,:] = np.random.permutation(50)
rand_mat = np.random.rand(50,50)
A = np.matmul(rand_mat, np.transpose(rand_mat)) # a random symmetric matrix
# do permutation
batch_size = x.shape[0] # infer batch size from inputs
permuted_matrices = np.zeros((batch_size, 50, 50))
for i in range(batch_size):
  permuted_matrices[i,:,:] = A[:,x[i,:]][x[i,:],:] # permute both rows and columns according to x[i,:]
```

But when I call my layer, I get an error `TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` (because of the for loop). If I instead use `tf.shape(x)[0]` instead of `x.shape[0]`, then I get `TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type 'NoneType' instead` (because of np.zeros). Is there a TensorFlow function I could use that would be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gather()` and `gather_nd()`:

```
r = 50 # use 10 to check
batch_size = 10
x = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, r), 0, r, tf.int32)
A = tf.range(r * r)
A = tf.reshape(A, (r, r))

ind = x[..., tf.newaxis]
output = tf.gather_nd(A, ind) # permute rows
output = tf.transpose(output, (0, 2, 1))
output = tf.gather(output, x, axis=1, batch_dims=1) # permute columns
output = tf.transpose(output, (0, 2, 1))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!